# Firebug's Script panel displays sources like @conn0source

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebug

I have an AngularJS app and when I try to debug it in Firebug, I get all these sources with weird names in the *Script* panel:

[image: List of JavaScript sources]

Does anybody know what they are or how I can get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those items are dynamically evaluated scripts (introduced via `eval()`, `new Function()` or event handlers).

These scripts don't have a URL assigned, so Firebug [assigns them an arbitrary one](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/20b8549fbaedee8c6b9ac0d3230e4475904f9979/extension/content/firebug/debugger/script/sourceTool.js#L171-L173).

In order to assign a meaningful name or URL, the author of the web page can add a "//# sourceURL" statement.
See http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-label-dynamic-scripts-with-sourceurl-directive/ for more info on that.

See the [related documentation in the Firebug wiki](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Script_Location_Menu).

If you don't want to see dynamically evaluated scripts, you can disable their display by choosing *Show static Scripts* from the [Script Type Menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Script_Type_Menu).

[image: *Show static Scripts* option within Script Type Menu]

*Note: This was also [asked in the Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebug/0Q1cp3KhSl0/discussion).*